# Is there a method in xamarin forms like wizard multi step progress

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm created UI for an application and struct at here
My requirement is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcaYE.png)

Please do help

Comment: no, you would need to build this yourself

Comment: can you help me with what concept to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reality of this situation is, Xamarin will not do this for you. It wouldn't really be too difficult to do yourself however. The layout would really just be a Grid with 2 Rows, the top row being the progress indicator, and the bottom being where the user interacts.

Regarding the progress indicator, I would just just use 3 images of the overall indicator with 1 of the 3 "stages" highlighted (in each image). Then just flip between each image based on what stage the user is at.

For the user interaction, you could just flip between views with your UI content on it. After a user fills out the data on the first few, hide that view and bring in the next view. You would only really need to work with Labels, Buttons, Images, Frames, Entires, and Grids. If you plan on animating things, it will be a bit more work, but a couple YouTube videos and a read over the Microsoft docs should get you to where you need to be.

If you still have troubles maybe look for some demos for something similar?